# How do I use Turbolinks and local_time together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I've noticed recently, probably since installing Rails 5 that the local_time gem doesn't work properly on pages where the link was internal (through turbolinks).  If the link to the page was external or the browser refreshed, or turbolinks is disabled, local_time works properly.

Does anyone know how to use these together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to initialize the local time on TurboLinks load.  This event provides a chance to do those things that would have run at document ready. The JavaScript is:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  LocalTime.run();
});
```